# ListView is not updated after deleting record in second Activity

Tags: java, android

I have ListView Activity which displays a list of saved records from Sqlite. By pressing each index it navigates me to the next Activity which displays values depending on which ListView index has been pressed.

Everything works as expected, but whenever I press delete button in the Second Activity it navigates me back to ListView Activity, but it does not update the `ListView`. So I have to go backward one Activity again and reopen it so it finally starts updating the `ListView`.

Here is my code for ListView activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_artist);

    artistList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.artistList);
    databasehandler = new SqliteHandler(ViewArtistActivity.this);
    allArtists = databasehandler.getAllArtists();
    artistName = new ArrayList<>();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if (allArtists.size() > 0) {
        for (int i=0; i < allArtists.size(); i++) {
            ArtistModel artistModel = allArtists.get(i);
            artistName.add(artistModel.getArtistName());
        }
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ViewArtistActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, artistName);
    artistList.setAdapter(adapter);

    artistList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            singleArtistDetails = new ArrayList<>();

            ArtistModel artistModel = allArtists.get(position);
            singleArtistDetails.add(artistModel.getArtistName());
            singleArtistDetails.add(artistModel.getArtistDOB());
            singleArtistDetails.add(artistModel.getArtistBiography());

            Intent intent = new Intent(ViewArtistActivity.this, SavedArtistDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("NAME", singleArtistDetails.get(0));
            intent.putExtra("DOB", singleArtistDetails.get(1));
            intent.putExtra("BIOGRAPHY", singleArtistDetails.get(2));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no such mechanism in case with ArrayAdapter. You should learn Activity lifecycle and manually reload list after returning to this activity, in this case.

Comment: for my button in Second Activity after doing deletion action I have set finish() method which brings me back to ListView Activity but it is still not updated. Are there any other methods similar to finish() which will reload first activity instead of just closing active activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `onResume` function in your `ListViewActivity`. Repopulate your `artistName` array and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    allArtists = databasehandler.getAllArtists();

    // Clear the list
    artistName.clear();

    if (allArtists.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < allArtists.size(); i++) {
            ArtistModel artistModel = allArtists.get(i);
            artistName.add(artistModel.getArtistName());
        }
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

To learn more about activity lifecycle, please refer to the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Comment: I have tried doing this. However, I am getting very unexpected results :( Now onCreate recently added values are updated twice and when I press on one of the indexes my app crashes. I have tried similar solutions before using onResume and onStart but none of these worked as expected.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clear the list. The answer is updated. Please check.

Comment: Actually I just managed to fix it in completely different way. To the delete button in Second Activity I have added new Intent which navigates to the ListView Activity and it worked. Also I have used finish() to close Second Activity. Which of these would be better implementation practice in this case?

Comment: Yes, that's another way. However, you can just keep the old activity and gain the automatic stacking of activities by overriding the lifecycle functions which is recommended.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for help. It's fixed now. I will read more about the activity lifecycle to learn more about it.